# Does Rosemary repel mosquitoes from home?

Tags: pest-control, insect

Setting out the mosquito repellent plants in your home is the best option to keep mosquitos away. Plants not only avoid mosquitoes away but also provide you fresh air to breathe.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is plainly stated in the title and is quite specific. I'm not sure why it requires clarity or would be considered opinion-based.

Comment: I'd say that any one-sentence question could use some clarification, and the whole topic of "natural pest repellant" is very likely to attract opinionated answers.

Comment: Is this really a topic for "Home Improvement" rather than "Gardening & Landscaping" or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a published source, USA Today, that has published an article discussing rosemary as well as other plants that repel mosquitoes.

[USA Today Article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2016/06/04/bug-mosquito-repellent-plants/85400368/)

I'm not making any claims as to the effectiveness of any of these, so take this for what it's worth.  My guess is that these can't hurt and would make a nice garden.  To quote what they say about rosemary:

> 5. Rosemary. Though you'll want to plant an herb garden for cooking, rosemary repels flies and mosquitoes.
>
> It also has a pungent scent that drives away other bugs, including
>   cabbage moths. It does well in hot dry weather, and thrives in
>   containers, so you can set it in various places around the garden.

Comment: USA Today is maybe one step up from  The Daily Mail when it comes to reliability as a source of science.

Comment: You might at least site _some_ information from the source.  If that link dies, this answer has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The statements made in the body are unsupported.  In particular, plants are almost exactly oxygen-neutral (vs CO2), despite what you were incorrectly told in grade school.  Mosquitos don't care in the least what plants are around.  They go after regions with higher than average CO2 content on the assumption that a tasty meal is exhaling there.

To keep mosquitos out of your home, use screens.

Comment: I don’t see this as an answer to the question but more of a slam.- I did find that rosemary can relieve the itching of a mosquito bite. And some believe the strong smell deters them, it has been shown that rosemary oil in the skin will also deter them from biting. But other than these things no rosemary has not been proven to deter mosquitoes.

Comment: I like the answer; any snarkiness correlates with the presumptive nature of the OP's statement, as fact, that plants are the "best option to keep mosquitos away". If plants were the "best" way then we wouldn't have DEET or mosquito netting, and mosquito borne disease would be epidemic. This answer *indirectly* addresses the question, and correctly refutes the other non-fact about "fresh air". +1

Comment: @EdBeal  itch relief is hardly a "repellant", though!

Comment: It also said the oil was a deterrent but not the plant itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rosemary plant is an aromatic and distinctive herb with a sweet, and resinous flavor. Their woody aroma is exactly what keeps the mosquitoes, cabbage moths and carrot flies, away from your house. Rosemary plant prefers warm and dry temperatures.  These plants can be trimmed in any shape and size and can be used for decoration purposes. Rosemary is a perennial plant that lives more than 2 years. According to the research, it is found that the crude ethanolic rosemary extract slowed the spread of human leukemia and breast carcinoma cells.